# Vibrational Spectrums of HI, HBr, HF, and HCl

Tags: physical-chemistry, reference-request

Do you all know of any large graphs for the vibrational spectrums of HI, HBr, HF, and HCl? I need graphs that are large enough to see the spacing between the peaks in the spectra of HCl, HBr, and HI.

Alternately, if you know of any raw data sets for any of the above, that would work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried searching NIST?  Here is a link to the IR spectrum of HBr.  (http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C10035106&Mask=80#IR-Spec) The others should be easy to find as well as these are simple systems that have more than likely been previously and extensively investigated. (I don't know how large you need the spacings. This first inquiry should make for a good point of reference). Also, do you only care about experimental data or will spectra generated from computational methods be sufficient?

Comment: Computational methods would be fine, I'm just trying to use it to show the effects of isotopes in molecules to high school students.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too quickly.  These diatomics will only have one fundamental vibrational mode (one peak) so computational methods on a single gas-phase diatomic won't help you there (i.e. there won't be any splitting) .

Comment: For $\ce{HCl}$ I would suggest [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022285280901046).

Answer (score 2):

The fine structure in the diatomic vibrational spectra is based on various population of the rotational levels.

The best demonstration of isotopic effects in vibrational spectra is to switch hydrogen for deuterium.

The frequency of vibration (from [Hooke's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law#Harmonic_oscillator) adapted to a harmonic oscillator) is given by:

$$\nu = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{\mu}}$$

where $k$ is the force constant of the oscillator and $\mu$ is the reduced mass:

$$\mu=\dfrac{M_1M_2}{M_1+ M_2}$$

Switching $\ce{HCl}$ to $\ce{DCl}$ has a much larger effect than the two chlorine isotopes (35 and 37):

- $\ce{H^{35}Cl}, \ \mu\approx\frac{35}{36}=0.972$
- $\ce{H^{37}Cl}, \ \mu\approx\frac{37}{38}=0.974$
- $\ce{D^{35}Cl}, \ \mu\approx\frac{70}{37}=1.892$
- $\ce{D^{37}Cl}, \ \mu\approx\frac{74}{39}=1.898$

The difference between $\ce{^{35}Cl}$ and $\ce{^{37}Cl}$ is in the third decimal place.

Here is a nice Google Image search for the [vibrational spectra of HCl and DCl](https://www.google.com/search?q=hcl%20and%20dcl%20ir)